# CS50 credit card validation: why is printf not printing the same number that was inputted?

Tags: c, printf, cs50

I'm trying to do the credit card exercise for cs50. Why is it that when I store the credit card number as a variable called 'number' and then immediately print that variable, a random number is printed and not my entered credit card number?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long number = get_long("Number: ");
    printf("%lo\n",number);
}
```

I am prompted to enter the number and put in 1234567890123

```
Number: 1234567890123
```

But the number below is what comes out

```
21756176602313
```

Comment: `o` means octal (base 8).

Comment: If you've got a credit card number, it should not be stored as a number. You should have it as a string. Even though all the characters are digits, it's not really a "number".  If you're not going to perform arithmetic operations on it, then store it as a string.  This applies to other all-digit "numbers" like phone numbers, ZIP codes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The format specifier outputs in octal format:

```
printf("%lo\n",number);//%lo = unsigned long integer printed in octal digits.
         ^^
```

for base 10 it should be:

```
printf("%ld\n",number);//"%li" is also valid.
         ^^
```

Comment: You can use `%li` too.

Comment: @natalie889 [1234 is correctly printed as 1234](https://godbolt.org/z/zTGKj3j14) - unless you have a bug in some part of the program that you haven't shown.

Comment: @ryyker Yes. It's not valid on its own

Comment: That result of inputting 1234 and getting 2322 was the same when using long and %li  or long long and %lli, seems like this must be something wrong with my set up

Comment: @natalie889 2322 is base 8 for 1234, you obviously didn't change the `%lo`.

Comment: @ryyker The C standard specifies that a conversion specification (starting with `%`) must include a conversion specifier. `%l` doesn't include one.

Comment: @ryyker C18 (C23 draft) "7.21.6.1 The fprintf function" _"`l` (ell) Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long int
or unsigned long int argument; that a following n conversion specifier applies to
a pointer to a long int argument; that a following c conversion specifier applies to
a wint_t argument; that a following s conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a
wchar_t argument; or has no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion
specifier"_ - Nothing says the conversion specifier `l` can be used without that following char.

Comment: [n2310](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)

Comment: Typo: I said _"Nothing says the conversion specifier..."_ - I meant _"length specifier_". And [the C99 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) doesn't mention the length specifier `%l` being valid without a conversion specifier either. If your compiler accepts it, it's an extension.

Comment: Note that the three sources you list all have the same exact list in the same order. They must all have copied it from each other. They also all say that `%n` "prints nothing" but neglect to say that it writes into an output parameter.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Re “If your compiler accepts it, it's an extension”: If the compiler documents that it accepts it, it is an extension. If the compiler accepts it but does not document it, it is just garbage.

Answer (score 3):

The correct format specifier to print `long` in decimal (base 10) is `%ld` or `%li`.